# Unable to get all user from the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot which get/invite all users in my other server but when running this code I was only able to get one user ID which is my bot.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.members = True
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    server = client.get_guild(985156775152087053)
    for member in server.members:
        print(member)

client.run("Token")
```

Answer (score 3):

`client` does not have an attribute called `members`. `discord.Intents` has an attribute of `members`. 
So, you can try something like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also, consider using `Bot` instead of `Client`. See the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot)